# Why can't I do `null (Just 5)` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, option-type, foldable

The Hackage documentation for Maybe lists Foldable as one of Maybe's typeclasses. It also lists the following function:

```
null :: Maybe a -> Bool
```

It even links to this function's implementation (from `Foldable`):

```
null :: t a -> Bool
null = foldr (\_ _ -> False) True
```

...which seems rather reasonable. It works, too: I can, if I `import qualified Data.Foldable`, use `foldr` on Maybe values.

However, when I try to call `null` on a Maybe, Haskell thinks I want to use the null designed for lists:

```
Prelude> :t null
null :: [a] -> Bool
Prelude> null Nothing
<interactive>:3:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Maybe a1'
    In the first argument of `null', namely `Nothing'
    In the expression: null Nothing
    In an equation for `it': it = null Nothing
```

I know there is `isJust`, I'm just wondering how to call a function like `null` for any Foldable.

Comment: what GHC/base version are you using? because yes with base-4.8.x it's [`t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) but [`null` used to be `[a] -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:null)

Comment: @Carsten Yep, that was exactly it - Ubuntu Vivid is apparently still shipping [ghc 7.6.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ghc), which was released April  2013 and has an older version of base.

Comment: yeah sorry - saw your answer to late - btw you can use [Herbert V. Riedels PPA-Sources](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, I was running an older version of GHC (the default version for my OS), while the documentation was for the newest version (of course).

In GHC 7.10.2 at least, the `null` that you get out of Prelude supports Foldables (like Maybe) without having to import anything:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t null
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```

Comment: This is due to the [burning bridges proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude). Just in case you were wondering why `Foldable` gained so many additional functions and `Prelude`'s types changed so much between 7.8 and 7.10.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple functions called `null`. The one you're getting in ghci is from the `Prelude`, and it is `null :: [a] -> Bool`. The reason this happens is that everything from the `Prelude` is imported implicitly.

To get the right one you need to `import Data.Foldable (Foldable(null))`*, and to prevent ambiguity with the wrong one you need to `import Prelude hiding (null)`. Re-importing the `Prelude` explicitly like this prevents the implicit import that would happen otherwise.

*Or `import Data.Foldable (Foldable(..))` to get all of `Foldable`'s methods.

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't seem to work - I get `Module 'Data.Foldable' does not export 'null'`

Comment: @WanderNauta My mistake. Fixed.

Comment: It turns out updating GHC was enough to fix the problem - thanks again, though!